# How can I create a REST API for an existing MEAN Stack application?

Tags: rest, mean-stack

I am pretty new to MEAN Stack and REST API, so please be kind. I already have an application built in MEAN Stack without using REST API. I was wondering if it is possible to build a REST API on top of the existing app, or should I start over again from the beginning? If it is possible, then what should be the steps to do it?

Comment: This question is _way_ too broad to be answered in a venue like Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Venantius, I understand. However, perhaps a little guideline, or direction on what steps should I take, would be sufficient and very helpful.